# error with package imu_9_dof

Tags: quaternion, geometry-msgs, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and i'm trying to do a project starting with the imu sensor stick. While trying to convert the raw data (raw, pitch & yaw) from the IMU 9dof sensor to ros data, I've got a problem with this line:

```
   imu.orientation.x = tf::createQuaternionFromYaw(0.0);
```

And this derived the error:

```
   error: cannot convert ‘tf::Quaternion’ to ‘geometry_msgs::Quaternion_<std::allocator<void> >::_x_type {aka double}’ in assignment.
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61960/error-with-package-imu_9_dof/) by [Gisela](https://answers.ros.org/users/4803/gisela/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something along these lines should work:

```
tf::Quaternion q = tf::createQuaternionFromYaw(0.0);
tf::quaternionTFToMsg(q, imu.orientation);
```

See [tf::quaternionTFToMsg()](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a59d2fcbc5720f31a5e330f0e7c4a3721).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gisela](https://answers.ros.org/users/4803/gisela/) on 2013-05-02**:
Thank you! Right now I am working my imu sensor stick with an Arduino board. I've got the data from the imu printed out (roll, pitch and yaw). However I have to convert the raw data(roll, pitch and yaw) to ros capatible data and publish these data. So do you have any suggestions? Thank you again! :)